# CarrierWave: create thumb from unprocessed image

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I have the following code for a Rails image uploader:

```
class PhotoUploader < BaseUploader
  ...

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [80, 80]
  end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  process resize_to_fit: [618, 412]
  process convert: 'png'
  process :watermark
  process convert: 'jpg'

  def watermark
    manipulate! do |img|
      logo = Magick::Image.read("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/watermark.png").first
      img = img.composite(logo, Magick::NorthEastGravity, 0, 20, Magick::OverCompositeOp)
    end
  end

end
```

Basically, I want 2 things:

- Add a watermark to the original image
- Create a thumbnail of the original image (without the watermark)

However, it appears as though the watermark processing takes place before creating the thumbnail, is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's not possible as is. Any processing on the original version will affect all the `versions`.

The only way to do it is to keep the original version clean and create 2 versions from it: `version :thumb` and `version :watermarked`.